# Parasite + Wyrm combo - is it an insta-killer?

Tags: android-netrunner

Wyrm has the following text:

> 1[Credit]: Ice has -1 strength.

Parasite has the following text:

> Host ice has -1 strength for each virus counter on Parasite and is trashed if its strength is 0 or less.

If I understand this correctly, if I place a Parasite card on an ICe's, and use Wyrm's (somewhat expensive) ability to lower an ICe's strength, I can bring it down to 0 and then Parasite will kick in and kill it. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Yes, this combo works**.

Parasite will trash any ice as soon as it has zero (or lower) strength, regardless of how that strength was lowered (i.e. it doesn't only trigger from Parasite's counters).

Other cards that combo with Parasite include [Datasucker](http://www.cardgamedb.com/index.php/netrunner/android-netrunner-card-spoilers/_/datasucker-core):

> Whenever you make a successful run on a central server, place 1 virus counter on Datasucker.
>   **Hosted virus counter**: Rezzed piece of ice currently being encountered has -1 strength until the end of the encounter.

or [Ice Carver](http://www.cardgamedb.com/index.php/netrunner/android-netrunner-card-spoilers/_/ice-carver-core):

> All ice is encountered with its strength lowered by 1.

Comment: Just note that you have to "encounter" the ice before you can pump Wyrm up and then lower the target ice down to 0. This means a DataRaven will still tag you, a Tollbooth will still cost you 3C etc.

Comment: @Nick - True, but not if I use the Datasucker combo offered by Johno. Nice!

Comment: @AviadBenDov Its also true with Datasucker; you have to encounter ICE before you can use Datasucker on it. Only IceCarver will lower the Strength before the "on encounter" abilities trigger.

Comment: @AviadBenDov Nick is correct. "On encounter" effects are triggered before you get the opportunity to use paid abilities (such as the one on Datasucker). If Ice Carver reduces the strength to 0, Parasite can trash (e.g.) Tollbooth before the effect, because neither requires a paid ability to do so.